# Fibonacci program that continues as long as you want in C

Tags: c, function, fibonacci

What is asked of me is:

> You will write a C file with the main function with additional functions described
> below. Your Program will start calling part1 and part 2 in that order. For each part, you will
> receive the inputs from the user and print the output to the console. Details of the parts are
> further discussed below. Please pay attention to the output format. Any deviation from the
> shared format may be penalized regardless of the correct execution.
> Write a function that will read one integer from the command prompt as term number of
> Fibonacci Sequence. If the input number is not positive integer value then your program will
> print the message explaining the reason for ineligibility. Your function will continue until it
> gets the correct input. Print the Fibonacci Sequence elements as many as the number of input.
> Let the function continue working until it gets the ‘*’ input.
>
> Here, when you enter a positive integer into the program, it should show the elements of the Fibonacci number sequence. If it enters a string , float , or negative number I should give a warning but the program should continue until * a is pressed.

I did something for this program but I am struggling keeping the program running.

here is my code:

```
void calculate_fibonacci_sequence()
{
    int eleman;

    printf("Enter how many elements of the fibonacci sequence you want to see : ");

    scanf("%d", & eleman);

    if (eleman <= 0) {
        while (eleman <= 0) {
            printf("Please enter positive term(s) number: a \n");
            scanf("%d", & eleman);
            if (eleman > 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    if (eleman > 0) {
        printf("\n\n");

        int i, n, e1 = 1, e2 = 1;

        for (i = 1; i <= eleman; i++) {
            printf("        %d\n", e1);
            n = e1 + e2;
            e1 = e2;
            e2 = n;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exercise states that you should check for invalid input, but you do not check the return value of ```scanf```.

Comment: The ```while``` and ```if``` statements together do not make sense to me. A ```do while``` loop would be better here.

Comment: Also note that ```scanf``` would accept ```123abc``` as valid, and leave the trailing junk in the input buffer. Consider reading a whole line with ```fgets``` and then parse it with ```strtol```, ```sscanf```, etc. accordingly.

Comment: If [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) fails then it will leave the invalid input in the buffer, for the next input operation. That can easily lead to an infinite loop. Read whole lines using e.g. `fgets` instead, and then use `strtol` or `sscanf` to parse the input. But remember, always check what `sscanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Is it ```if``` statement before the ```for``` loop necessary? Don't you check for a positive number before exiting the first ```while``` loop?

Comment: *"I did something for this program but I am struggling keeping the program running."* ---> is unclear. Kindly restate the problem.

Comment: "Starting from 0 and 1, the first few values in the sequence are: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8..." -- Wikipedia... You need to work out how to start printing from the actual beginning of the sequence.

Comment: https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Answer (score 2):

It's better to break your code into separate functioning pieces. Start off by writing a function that reads a line of input and then parses it:

```
int read_int(long *number)
{
    char tmp[16];
    if (!fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin))
        return RETCODE_FAIL;
    
    if (!strcmp(tmp, "*\n"))
        return RETCODE_END;
    
    char *end;
    *number = strtol(tmp, &end, 10);
    
    if (errno == ERANGE)
        return RETCODE_RANGE;
    
    if (end == tmp)
        return RETCODE_EMPTY;
    
    if (*end && *end != '\n')
        return RETCODE_WARN;
    
    return RETCODE_SUCCESS;
}
```

[`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) reads an entire line from a given file (in this case, `stdin`, i.e. the keyboard by default) with that little extra `'\n'`. it returns `NULL` if it fails, so it's a good idea to test its return value.

[`strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) parses a string to an `long int`. The second argument gives more information about the parsing process, so it's used to check for errors.

Return codes are grouped in an `enum` like this:

```
enum RETCODE {
    RETCODE_FAIL = 0,
    RETCODE_END,
    RETCODE_RANGE,
    RETCODE_EMPTY,
    RETCODE_WARN,
    RETCODE_SUCCESS
};
```

Next, write your Fibonacci algorithm:

```
void print_fibonacci(long n)
{
    long e0, e1 = 0, e2 = 1;
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        e0 = e1;
        e1 = e2;
        e2 = e0 + e1;
        printf("%ld ", e2);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Now, your `main()` will be very straightforward:

```
int main(void)
{
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        long number = -1;
        
        switch (read_int(&number)) {
        case RETCODE_FAIL:
            puts("Internal error");
            break;
        case RETCODE_END:
            puts("Goodbye!");
            return 0;
        case RETCODE_RANGE:
            puts("Number is either too small or too big");
            break;
        case RETCODE_EMPTY:
            puts("<empty>");
            break;
        case RETCODE_WARN:
            puts("Invalid integer format");
            break;
        case RETCODE_SUCCESS:
            number < 0 ? puts("Number must be positive") : print_fibonacci(number);
            break;
        default:
            // This should never run
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Credits (& nice to look at as well): [A Beginners' Guide Away From `scanf()`](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 0):

Updating your code!!!

You are using many **if else** conditions again and again that is making the code terrible. I just optimized it by **do while loop**.

Point is that you are performing iterations in your **for loop** after prinitng massage so, it retains the value 1 for second iteration. Just print the massage after iteration...

Here is revised version of your code.........

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 void calculate_fibonacci_sequence()
  {

   int eleman;

  do
   {
    printf("Enter how many elements of the fibonacci sequence you want to see : ");
    scanf("%d", &eleman);
    } while (eleman < 0);

     printf("\n");

    int i, n, e1 = 1, e2 = 1;
   for (i = 1; i <= eleman; i++)
    {
    n = e1 + e2;
    e1 = e2;
    e2 = n;
      printf("%d\n", e1);
    }
}

int main()
{
calculate_fibonacci_sequence();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has the same problems as OP's. Aside: Is ```0``` a positive number?

Comment: Zero is not a positive number nor negative but still a number, you can take it as any of odd or even...for that you just have to add a statement to print 0 before the loop as in every case you have to start from zero